# Who carried the aron which traveled in front of the camp?

Tags: midrash, rashi, pentateuch-chumash, behaalotcha-parsha, bamidbar-numbers-book-of

Rashi describes how the aron (which contained the broken pieces of the first luchos and which was taken out with the Jewish army in times of battle) would travel in front of the camp in the desert. Rashi writes that the aron was in front of the camp by the distance of three days’ journey. Who was carrying this aron?

Comment: Seemingly, the Levites? https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9A_(%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8_%D7%93%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A1_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%98)/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%98

Answer (score 0):

Rashi on Bamidbar 10:35 says that when it came time to stop traveling, Moshe would call out “stand still, O Lord!”, in order that the Aron shouldn’t travel further.

So from the fact that Moshe would ask Hashem that the Aron shouldn’t travel further, it would appear that it traveled miraculously on its own!

Answer (score 0):

The [Birchas Asher](https://www.sefaria.org/Birkat_Asher_on_Torah%2C_Numbers.10.33.1?lang=he) on this passuk suggests that the Leviim carried it:

> כלומר ארון זה נוסע יחד עם בני גרשון ומררי שהקדימו את המחנה בשלושה ימים. רק נשארת השאלה, היכן נסע הענן המיישר להם את הדרך, לפני חלוצים אלה או לפני מחנה בני יהודה. (פ' בהעלתך תשנ"ז)